# NSTreeController get added child

Tags: cocoa, addchild, nstreecontroller

When NSTreeController -`(void)addChild:(id)sender` is called, is there a way to get the `NSManagedEntity` that was created?

The documentation mentions that the result of this method is deferred to the next loop run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't, because the object won't be created until after that method has returned. Internally, `NSTreeController` should call this method:

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)object atArrangedObjectIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Can you override that to your advantage instead?